# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE during installation with PHP 7.3

Tags: 8, installation

I'm trying to install Drupal 8 with PHP version `7.3.0RC4`.

When I go to `http://localhost` it redirects me to `http://localhost/core/install.php` with the empty response error.

I checked the Apache error log, nothing, edited the PHP config (`php.ini`) to display all errors but nothing shows up.

However, when I downgrade to PHP 5.6 it works. Is Drupal ready for PHP 7.3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drupal doesn’t officially (or unofficially as far as I’m aware) support PHP 7.3 at time of writing.

You should downgrade to PHP 7.2, and probably consider revising your operating procedures so you don’t end up using pre-release versions of PHP.

If you still see a problem, you probably haven’t configured Apache and mod_php correctly for the new version.

Comment: See also https://www.drupal.org/node/3060/qa and https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2989734 (think that is the parent issue)

Comment: With Drupal 8.6.4, there is PHP 7.3 support: https://www.drupal.org/node/3038583